# Promise is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to get a value back from this promise but it keeps returning undefined on my template.If you look at my getLabel function, I am getting the label in the argument which is a promise. I am resolving it and returning it to my title in my getMenuItems function which calls it originally. When I see it on the page, it comes back as undefined. I need some help understanding why.

```
angular.module("peanutModule").service("navigationService", ["registrationLink", "auctionLink", "webLabel", function(registrationLink, auctionLink, webLabel) {
  this.getMenuItems = function(menu) {
    return [{
      "title": "VIEW EVENT ITEMS",
      "href": auctionLink
    }, {
      "title": "REGISTER FOR " + getLabel(webLabel),
      "href": registrationLink
    }];
  };

  function getLabel(label) {
    var original = Promise.resolve(label);
    var cast = Promise.resolve(original);
    cast.then(function(value) {
      console.log('value: ' + value);
      return value;
    });
    console.log('original === cast ? ' + (original === cast));
  }

}]).service("ticketItemsService", ["APIDataProvider", "sharedOrganization", "ItemsCountFactory", function(APIDataProvider, sharedOrganization, ItemsCountFactory) {
  var dataProvider = new APIDataProvider("ItemsCount");
  dataProvider.setModelFactory(ItemsCountFactory);

  this.get = function() {
    return sharedOrganization.get().then(function(organization) {
      return dataProvider.get("organizations/" + organization.org_id + "/items");
    });
  };
}]).factory("registrationLink", ["slug", function(slug) {
  // return "https://test.net/register.php/?id=" + slug;
  return "https://test.net/thezone/" + slug + "/register";
}]).factory("auctionLink", ["slug", function(slug) {
  return "https://test.net/thezone/" + slug + "/items";
}]).factory("webLabel", ["sharedOrganization", function(sharedOrganization) {

  this.get = function() {
    return (isValidOrganization() ? $q.resolve : stackPromise)(org_data);
  };

  return sharedOrganization.get().then(function(organization) {
    return organization.web_label;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Youre not returning anything from `getLabel`, which is why its giving you `undefined`. Did you mean to say `return cast.then(...)`?

Comment: When I do a return on the cast.then, it gives me [object promise]. How do I resolve that?

Comment: Of course, that's how promises work. [Maybe make yourself more familiar with promises first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Promises do not make an asynchronous process synchronous. If `getLabel` performs an asynchronous action then you cannot return the result from the action in a synchronous fashion. The *caller* of `getLabel` has to know that `getLabel` is asynchronous and call it accordingly. OTOH, why are using promises inside `getLabel` in the first place? Is this just a placeholder for your actual code?

Comment: I added more code up top to explain some more on the code. I took over this code and I am trying my best to understand it.

Comment: I am trying to get the organization.web_label but it's not returning and it's giving me a promise instead. So I used the getLabel function as a way to extract it out but it still is not working. I can console.log organization.web_label and see the result but I have no way of getting it to my template. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The get method is the same on here as it's in the sharedOrganization dependency. I added it to clarify what that did.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to figure this one out. I set up my api so that I could call the api to get the actual value from the db and then I did a synchronous call to my db column through an XMLHTTPRequest.

```
.factory("webLabel",["slug", function (slug) {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/api/organizations/' + slug + '/label', false); 
request.send(null);

var label = request.response;

return label;
```

Comment: Guess what happens with browser window if the server connection freezes for some reason? Synchronous XHR request is an ugly hack that shouldn't be recommended to anyone who can read the answer. Especially since promise control flow is already in use.